# Python: TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable

Tags: python, mysql, kivy

I am creating a Python program in Kivy that allows users to sign in, or create a new account. I have a table of usernames and passwords in MySQL that the Python program refers to (via PyMySQL). When the new user enters a username that already exists, Python iterates through every username in the MySQL table, and if the username exists already, Python asks the user to enter a new password. The issue is that when the user attempts to enter a new username and Python runs through the code again I get the "TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable". I am puzzled because if the user enters a username that doesn't already exist the first time, I get no errors. When they attempt to enter the username again, I get the error.

Here is my .py main file code block that is giving me problems:

```
#Select all usernames from the database with the execute method
cur.execute("""SELECT username FROM patient_login""")

#Use the fetchall() method to get a list dictionary of all usernames
self.usernames_from_db = cur.fetchall()


#For each of the names in the list/dict of usernames
for names in self.usernames_from_db:

      #If the names username is equal to the username the user created
      if names['username'] == self.new_patient_username:

            #Display an error if username exists
            self.root.ids.new_username_error_box.text = 'Username taken'

            #Empty the username TextInput box
            self.root.ids.new_patient_username.text = ''

            #Empty the password TextInput box
            self.root.ids.new_patient_password.text = ''




        #Else store the username
        else:
            cur.execute("""INSERT INTO patient_login (username, 
                         password) VALUES ("%s", "%s")"""
                         %s(self.new_patient_username, 
                            self.new_patient_password))

            #Commit to database
            user_db_conn.commit()#Commit it to the database







            #Select the ID for the username with the execute method 
            cur.execute("""SELECT ID FROM patient_login WHERE username="%s"
                        """%(self.new_patient_username))


            #Use the fetchall() method to get the ID stored into a list dict
            self.user_id_dict = cur.fetchall()

            #Get the 0 (first) index in the dictionary of ID's.
            self.user_id_index = self.user_id_dict[0]

            #Get the 'ID' VALUE in the key value pair of the ID dict. Make 
            self.user_id_string = str(self.user_id_index['ID'])

            #Get the integer value of the user id as well
            self.user_id_integer = int(self.user_id_string)

            #Display the ID in a TextInput Box so that the user knows their
            self.root.ids.new_username_error_box.text = self.user_id_string
```

Here is my .kv code:

```
  Screen:

    name: 'Create_Username'

    GridLayout:
        rows: 4
        columns: 2
        spacing: 2
        padding: 2

        Label: 
            text: 'Username'

        TextInput:
            text:''
            id: new_patient_username


        Label:
            text:'Password'

        TextInput:
            text:''
            id: new_patient_password

        TextInput:
            text:''
            id:new_username_error_box

        Button:
            text: 'Enter Data'
            on_release: app.new_patient_username()
            background_normal: 'red_button_background.jpg'

        Button:
            text:'Continue'
            on_release: root.current = 'Create_Account'
            background_normal: 'red_button_background.jpg'

        Button:
            text: 'Back'
            on_release: root.current = 'Sign_In_To_Account'
            background_normal: 'red_button_background.jpg'
```

Here is the error message displayed to the user when they enter a username that already exists: [image]

When they enter a new username, this is the Traceback that I get:

```
     on_release: app.new_patient_username()
     TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable
```

As you can see, when the user presses the "store data" button a second time, a tracebook occurs. However, when they press the Button the first time and attempt to store a username and password, no error occurs.

Comment: This error happens when you call unicode object as a function. Try without parenthesis `app.new_patient_username`

Comment: @RaghavPatnecha When I call it without parenthesis, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: I understand but the way you are doing it is also wrong because `new_patient_username()` is not a callable function

Comment: I'm kicking myself. I accidently gave the function the same name as the object new_patient_username. Since they had the same name, Python was calling the object instead of the def function. When I changed the name of the function, it worked fine. Thanks so much because I would've missed that if you hadn't have pointed out that it was calling the object.

Comment: Good to see that you found out yourself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Kicking myself. The name of my function matched the name of a variable within my function. When I called the function, it was calling the variable (can't call a string/Unicode object), instead of calling the function. I simply changed the name of the function, and the code worked fine.

Comment: Hah, thanks, I did the same thing. Your post saved me a lot of work :)